# Python os.walk reports DIR as FILE walking external NTFS drive with macos on Macbook 2021

Tags: python, os.walk, macos-monterey

With Macbook 2021 (arm64).

```
uname -a
Darwin MacBook.local 21.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:01 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

External drive, SSD2TB,  is NTFS.

```
diskutil info disk4
   Device Identifier:         disk4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk4
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk4
   Device / Media Name:       External

   Volume Name:               SSD2TB
   Mounted:                   Yes
   Mount Point:               /Volumes/SSD2TB

   Content (IOContent):       None
   File System Personality:   NTFS
   Type (Bundle):             ntfs
   Name (User Visible):       Windows NT File System (NTFS)
```

The simplest of tests, is to simply report a directory name for each cycle, e.g.

```
python3
Python 3.10.1 (main, Dec 31 2021, 10:22:35) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, os.path
>>> os.chdir("/Volumes/SSD2TB/Photos")
>>> from glob import glob
>>> glob('*')
['Pictures']
>>> for d,dd,f in os.walk('.'): print(f"{dd}")
... 
[]
>>> os.path.isdir('Pictures')
True
>>> for d, dd, f in os.walk('.'):
...     print(f"{f}")
... 
['.DS_Store', 'Pictures']
>>> for d, dd, f in os.walk('.'):
...     print(f"{d}")
... 
.
```

Does anyone understand why the sub-directory in '.' is getting reported as a file in os.walk (by getting returned in the 'f' variable?
And the 'dd' variable which should be the list of directories returns an empty list.

I thought at first this was some quirk in Spyder that I was using, running python in the console,  but as you can see, I get exactly the same result running python directly.

One final note.
If I try the same test in a path on the local drive, then everything behaves as expected.  Directories are reported in variable 'dd' and files in 'f'.

Comment: Although not an answer to the question.  I have circumvented the issue with my own 'walking' function using pathlib2's iterdir method. E.g.
```def recursedir(path):
    d = path.resolve()
    dd = [ x for x in d.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
    f  = [ x for x in d.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
    if len(dd) == 0:
        yield (d, dd, f)
    else:
        for xd in dd:
            yield from recursedir( d / xd )
```

Comment: This isn't technically off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you may have an easier time getting an answer on Super User, AskDifferent, Unix & Linux, or one of the other sister Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Contrary to my first 'comment', the defined recursive function 'recursedir' only traverses the leaf directories. For some cases this might be sufficient. So needs a bit more thought.

Comment: So, the `if len(dd) == 0:` clause forces the function to only return the leaf directory results, removing the 'if' and 'else' fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something to do with the way os.walk interfaces with Apple's NTFS handler.  If you use a proprietary NTFS tool for MacOS, then os.walk works as expected.

Check out my alternative code for pathlib to walk with Apple NTFS or any other.

https://superuser.com/questions/1701107/macos-with-external-ntfs-default-read-only-python-os-walk-will-not-recurse-th